# Unable to use TensorFlow in python IDE

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I did the pip install through the terminal but when I import TensorFlow in IDLE or any .py file It  can't find the tf module.. How do I download TF such that I can use it in IDLE to code?
If it makes a difference I'm using a MacBook Air

Comment: Your IDE probably uses another version of python. Be sure to install the tensorflow in python's IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming IDLE means IDE here.

Generally you should able to use teansorflow as soon as you have executed `pip install tensorflow`.

Can you provide detail of IDE, and what error you are getting while importing tensorflow in IDE.

Please check below:

-> Have you run command `pip install tensorflow` and it was executed successfully.

-> Have you imported tensorflow in .py file with `import tensorflow as tf`.